# VBA sort Difference Excel 2010 vs 2013

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

This line

```
wsCheckAll.Range("NR2:NR" & TicCount).Sort Key1:=wsCheckAll.Columns("NR"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

In excel 2010 sorts the range "NR2:NR" & TicCount fine.

In excel 2013 the header NR1 gets sorted into the list and the sort is not even correct more or less just jumbles everything up. The list could be strings or doubles or ints

I have tried other ways of sorting such as:

```
    With wsCheckAll.Range("NR2:NR" & TicCount).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

with no such luck. I used the first method with no problems in all my macros before switching to 2013 and now nothing works. does anyone have any insight into this? I can seem to find documentation on a difference or anyone else having headers sorted into a range.

Comment: I generated a workbook in Excel 2013, placed a header in cell NR1, numerical values in cells NR2:NR20, set the variable TicCount to 20 and the wsCheckAll to my worksheet and ran your initial code.  It correctly sorted the numerical values.  Are there values in the columns surrounding column NR or anything else that is different about your case?

Comment: If I changed the sort to be on range "NR1:NR" & TicCount, it correctly put my Header at the bottom, so was not including it in the initial sort.

Comment: Try it on a list of text

Comment: Instead of *try it on a list of text*, what if you edited your question and provided some sample data so we had something to test with similar to what you're using, instead of having to play 20 questions with you in the comments?

Comment: @KenWhite he asked what was different in my case, so I said text and then appended my question to say the list could be a set of text int or double. Ill add sample data but it doesnt matter you can write dog cat mouse with header animals and its probably faster than copying the sample data but that doesnt matter the question is specific about the need to address the vba sorting routine differences between 2010 and 2013

Comment: I was referring specifically to the comments here, where @OpiesDad explained how things were tested (and worked properly), and your response was *Try it on a list of text*. Rather than that, edit your question and provide some sample data that isn't working for you so we can reproduce the problem. You want **our help** to solve **your problem**; you should want to make it as easy for us to help you as possible.

Comment: I put in a whole list of 19 colors ("red", "blue", "yellow", "magenta") in cells NR2:NR20 with cell NR1 containing "Header" with the same conditions as before and it gave the same results.  I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: Are there other values in the columns around column NR?

Comment: I put values in the columns surrounding NR and got the same result.  Something else is going on with your workbook/code.

Comment: @OpiesDad hmm yea I appreciate the effort, I was running this myself to further try and narrow the scope and occasionally it sorts properly and occasionally it sorts in the header when I run the macro on another computer something wacky is definitely going on. Too bad documentation is pretty basic surrounding this